# Posting attachments to apostrophe-headless

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm having trouble uploading images via REST-API to Apostrophe-CMS. I use an express Proxy, so the file is not sent directly from form submit. Instead, I send it base64 encoded to my proxy server and from there to apostrophe. Here's my express code:

```
app.post('/update-image', function (req, res) {
  const image = req.body.image
  if (image) {
    api.post('attachments', {file: image}, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('error:', error)
    })
  }
})
```

But what I get is "Error: content-type missing boundary". I tried to manually set "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" - this fixed this error but another one says "stream ended unexpectedly". I've also tried to convert it back to an image file with the same outcome. If I use Postman, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who experienced the same problem, this is my working solution:

```
{
  headers: { 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}` }
}
```

where formData is the FormData Object.

Comment: What is your "api" object here? That's not something that is included in apostrophe-headless, which is a documented REST API, not a JS library for invoking it. It sounds like your issue was in convincing the client software you're using to make a proper upload request.

Comment: My API Object is an Axios Instance.