# Inserting/Updating pieces and its fields via (apostrophe-headless) REST API

Tags: postman, apostrophe-cms

Am am currently using Postman to test the api results. I have been following the apostrophe headless docs, since am completely new to this. so what i need is to submit a post request in Postman to add a piece and its fields from REST api. I have got the bearer token and login was success. but when i insert a piece with body as JSON schema. am getting a error message.
May be the way am doing is wrong. so can one one help me in Making a post request to add piece and fields through POSTMAN atleast?

Comment: Hi Razana. I'm on the Apostrophe team. Do you recall the error message you received when you left the required fields out? I want to see if we should make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the question quite right. You should add some of your inputs, error message, url, pics and etc. to clarify the problem.
However, if you need an example to how to use postman to make a POST request, it's like this:

1. Select the POST method and insert the API URL (The landing url for POST method not the view and etc.)
   [image: Add a Post method]
2. Go to headers Tab and add the Authorization token to header
   [image: Add Authorization token]
3. Select the Body tab; Then raw type and finally JSON type. Now insert the Json body and click Send.
   [image: Add body]
4. You can see the result of webservice call on the top of response window. If it returned 200, everything was OK.
   [image: Response]

Comment: Thankyou so much for this sir @Saadat , i really helped.
I have followed all these steps and still couldn't receive a 200 , and may be it is because of the format of the  apostrophe schema in the body. If i could figure out how to write that schema ,may be i can solve the issue.

Comment: Can you provide a body example that your are passing to your question? like the one I used in the above example ( like {"summondId": 19338}). Also can you put a snap shot of error in your question. That will be more helpful. You said there may be some problem with "apostrophe schema"; but without example, I really can not understand what you mean. Try to fill up all information you can provide to clarify the question. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe this link helps to solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172573/posting-attachments-to-apostrophe-headless

Comment: Thankyou so much sir! I got the issue solved already...problem was related to the  apostrophe's schema, the scheme should contain some default parameters like slug&title  etc...but i was only giving my heading, text.. properties. Thanks alot for your valuable attention.  @Saadat